# Why is one of my div containers got pushed to the second row when using col-md-4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]I want the three div containers to line up side by side with a max-width of 1044px. I tried using col-md-4, because I have margin:20px, it pushed the third div container to the second row. I read up online, some people suggested using a div class="row", I tried that, end result is the same. 
Here is my HTML:

```
 <div class="engineering-section col-xs-12">
          <div class="engineering-section-title title-text text-center">Engineering</div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="card-container">
              <div class="card-section col-md-4">
                <div class="mdl-card__media">
                  <img src="img/engineer-1.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                  <span class="mdl-typography--font-light mdl-typography--subhead">V8.8 aspenONE Enginnering Suite (May 2015)</span>
                  <div class="checksum">
                  <a class="info_checksum" href="#">Checksum</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card_actions">
                   <a class="card-links" href="#">
                     Download Now
                     <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                   </a>
                </div><!--end card_actions-->
              </div><!--end mdl-cell-->
              <div class="card-section col-md-4">
                <div class="mdl-card__media">
                  <img src="img/engineer-2.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                  <span class="mdl-typography--font-light mdl-typography--subhead">V8.8 aspenONE Process Manuals and Process Tools</span>
                  <div class="checksum">
                  <a class="info_checksum" href="#">Checksum</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card_actions">
                   <a class="card-links" href="#">
                     Download Now
                     <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                   </a>
                </div><!--end card_actions-->
              </div><!--end mdl-cell-->
              <div class="card-section col-md-4">
                <div class="mdl-card__media">
                  <img src="img/engineer-3.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                  <span class="mdl-typography--font-light mdl-typography--subhead">Aspen License Deployment Assistant</span>
                  <div class="checksum">
                  <a class="info_checksum" href="#">Checksum</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card_actions">
                   <a class="card-links" href="#">
                     Download Now
                     <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                   </a>`enter code here`
                </div><!--end card_actions-->
              </div><!--end mdl-cell-->
          </div><!--end row-->
          </div><!--end card-container-->
```

Comment: Do you have any custom css also. If yes , then post it

Comment: @Sijie Wang why you are applying the margin? keep the cols below from top or increasing the space between cols

Comment: how do you increase the spacing between cols?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal The code is here https://jsfiddle.net/Swathi56/tya11gux/ not sure if this helps cuz images etc are not showing.

Comment: @SijieWang you wana increase the space between cols or just wana increase the space between top and 3 cols?

Comment: basically I have 3 div, they are card style div, if I remove the margin, the 3 cards are squished against each other, I need to give them breathing room, that's why I used margin. What's the alternative solution rather than using margin?

Comment: I just added a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Remove custom styles of `margin` from card-section class. It will work

Comment: Removing the margin will make the 3 div tightly squished against each other which is not what I want to achieve. I like to give them some breathing room.

Comment: It won't happen because col-md-4 apply margin in between the sibling elements. Did you really observed that on fiddle

Comment: Well, I tried removing margin:20px in my code, and that left the 3 boxes with no space in between.

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow these 3 rules :

- Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or
  .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.
- Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns.
- Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.

It should look like this :

```html
<div class="container-fluid"><!--<div class="container">-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See this link for more information about the Bootstrap responsive design :
http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong here

```
<div class="card-section col-md-4">
```

Put `card-section` inside `col-md-4`

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card-section">
```

it can give you the space between 3 cols and you can style the content too

and remove `margin: 20px;` it's unnecessary now.

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/au32wot3/2/)

Comment: Excellent! That fixed it! Thanks!